# How to do Fold in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have data in the following format

```
 id    subid      text
 1     1          Hello
 1     2          World
 1     3          !
 2     1          B
 2     2          B
 2     3          Q
```

And would like it in this format:

```
 id  fold
 1   HelloWorld!
 2   BBQ
```

How could I accomplish it in T-SQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would strongly suggest against that.  That is the sort of thing that should be handled in your application layer.

But... if you must:
[Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Comment: WOW those examples are intense.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by intense.

Comment: seemingly very involved and abstracted.

Comment: Agreed.  However, that's why I suggest against doing it in T-SQL and handling it in the application layer.

Answer (score 3):

a temp table and a cursor leap to mind...

Dear Downvoters: a temp table and a cursor have got to be at least as efficient as the recursive-query and custom-function solutions accepted above. Get over your fear of cursors, sometimes they are the most efficient solution. Sometimes they are the only solution. Deal with it.

EDIT: cursor-based solution below. Note that it has none of the limitations of the non-cursor (and more complicated) solutions proposed elsewhere, and performance is probably about the same (hard to tell from a six-row table of course).

and please, don't abandon the main for-each construct of sql just because some blogger says "it's bad"; use your own judgement and some common sense. I avoid cursors whenever possible, but not to the point where the solution is not robust.

```
--initial data table
create table #tmp (
    id int,
    subid int,
    txt varchar(256)
)

--populate with sample data from original question
insert into #tmp (id,subid,txt) values (1, 1, 'Hello')
insert into #tmp (id,subid,txt) values (1, 2, 'World')
insert into #tmp (id,subid,txt) values (1, 3, '!')
insert into #tmp (id,subid,txt) values (2, 1, 'B')
insert into #tmp (id,subid,txt) values (2, 2, 'B')
insert into #tmp (id,subid,txt) values (2, 3, 'Q')

--temp table for grouping results
create table #tmpgrp (
    id int,
    txt varchar(4000)
)

--cursor for looping through data
declare cur cursor local for
    select id, subid, txt from #tmp order by id, subid

declare @id int
declare @subid int
declare @txt varchar(256)

declare @curid int
declare @curtxt varchar(4000)


open cur

fetch next from cur into @id, @subid, @txt

set @curid = @id
set @curtxt = ''

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
    if @curid <> @id begin
        insert into #tmpgrp (id,txt) values (@curid,@curtxt)
        set @curid = @id
        set @curtxt = ''
    end
    set @curtxt = @curtxt + isnull(@txt,'')
    fetch next from cur into @id, @subid, @txt
end

insert into #tmpgrp (id,txt) values (@curid,@curtxt)

close cur

deallocate cur

--show output
select * from #tmpgrp

--drop temp tables
drop table #tmp
drop table #tmpgrp
```

Comment: @[StingyJack]: except when they're the only efficient solution

Comment: @StingyJack: Cursors definitely have their place.  However, as all have mentioned, this is not the place.

Comment: @StingyJack: cursor solution added

Comment: @[Jason Lepack]: cursor solution added

Comment: @AviewAnew: sometimes there's no school like the old school, see edits

Comment: Yes, cursors are bad unless you have no other option. I have _had_ to use them before, but my point was more that they should be avoided like the plague if at all possible. Your example should be declaring a FAST_FORWARD since you are read-only and only moving forward.

Comment: @Steve I don't really understand why you directed it at me, I completely believe in choosing the best tool for the job even if people are scared of it (I actually use gotos occasionally).  I accepted Jason's because I think it's the right mix of caution and completeness

Comment: @AviewAnew: I directed a comment at you so you would notice another solution, that's all!

Answer (score 1):

```
declare  @tmp table (id int, subid int,txt varchar(256) )  
--populate with sample data from original question 
insert into @tmp (id,subid,txt) values (1, 1, 'Hello') 
insert into @tmp (id,subid,txt) values (1, 2, 'World') 
insert into @tmp (id,subid,txt) values (1, 3, '!') 
insert into @tmp (id,subid,txt) values (2, 1, 'B') 
insert into @tmp (id,subid,txt) values (2, 2, 'B') 
insert into @tmp (id,subid,txt) values (2, 3, 'Q')
```

**Solution**

```
Select id, fold = (Select cast(txt as varchar(100)) from @tmp t2 where t1.id = t2.id for xml path(''))
from @tmp t1
group by t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this in a function for a single execution...

```
DECLARE @returnValue varchar(4000)

SELECT @returnValue = ISNULL(@returnValue + ', ' +  myTable.text, myTable.text)
FROM myTable 

RETURN @returnValue
```

For a small number of records this will work... any more than 5 or 10 is too many for a SQL function and it needs to be moved to app layer as others have suggested.